# Generate image thumbnail from existing CGImage with ImageIO?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to generate a thumbnail from an existing CGImage with the help of the function [CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageSource/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex).

In all examples that I found the provided image source is created with the help of the image's url.

Since I don't have any URLs -only the image data- I tried like this:

```
func createThumbnailForImage(image: CGImage, size: Int) -> CGImage?
{
    var provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(image)

    if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithDataProvider(provider, nil)
    {
        let swiftDict = [
            kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize as String : size,
            kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageIfAbsent as String : true
        ]

        let nsDict = swiftDict as NSDictionary
        let cfDict = nsDict as CFDictionary

        return CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource, 0, cfDict)
    }

   return nil
}
```

The result I get is always nil.

My guess is that something is wrong with the image source but cannot really identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are implementation thumbnail generation for Swift 3

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import ImageIO

class PhotoUtils: NSObject {

static func thumbnail(url:CFURL) -> UIImage {
    let src = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url, nil)
    return thumbnailImage(src: src!)
}

static func thumbnail(data imageData:CFData) -> UIImage {
    let src = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData, nil)
    return thumbnailImage(src: src!)
}

static private func thumbnailImage(src: CGImageSource) -> UIImage {
    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    let w = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 3) * scale
    let d : [NSObject:AnyObject] = [
        kCGImageSourceShouldAllowFloat : true as AnyObject,
        kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform : true as AnyObject,
        kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways : true as AnyObject,
        kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize : w as AnyObject
    ]
    let imref = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(src, 0, d as CFDictionary)
    return UIImage(cgImage: imref!, scale: scale, orientation: .up)
}

}
```